# Subprocess opens PowerShell, runs commands, then dies

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell, subprocess

I've written some code that uses the Python `subprocess` module to open a PowerShell window, then run a command in that same window. The PS window opens, then almost immediately closes. The code below will open a PS window and leave it open if I removed the second item from `cmd`.

```python
import subprocess
cmd = ['powershell', 'ls']
prompt = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-noexit` argument as follows (`-noprofile` is not mandatory):

```
import subprocess
cmd = ['powershell', '-noprofile', '-noexit', '&', 'ls *.csv']
prompt = subprocess.call ( cmd )
```

**Result**:

[image: Powershell from python]

Answer (score 0):

Any reason to not use [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) instead? I think it would do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you forgot to `communicate` with process
Simply add a line

```
output, error = prompt.communicate()  # this is to start the process
print(output) # add stdout=subprocess.PIPE
print(error)  # add stderr=subprocess.PIPE
```

PS: I can't help you with powershell because i don't know powershell